# Boot-Repair cancel itself

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

Here is my boot info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10844469

When trying to boot I get
Grub Loading Stage 1.5
wait..
Error 22

My workstation has dual boot Vista (sic!) and Ubuntu at least 14

I booted with a Ububtu install DVD in Try mode.

Installing and running boot-repair
First it complains about not having enough space on partition /dev/sda5 (... partition is nearly full ...) I deleted games and openoffice from it, and than run again boot-repair and get:
grub-pc purge cancelled. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

Any suggestions would be very appreciated

Comment: You have the very obsolete Ubuntu 9.04 with grub legacy (0.97). Your error messages are from grub legacy. Boot-Repair really only works with grub2 and only with current versions of Ubuntu that have repositories available to download new copies of grub2 to make repairs. You need to install a current version of Ubuntu. You live installer is 14.04, so  if you have your data well backed up just overinstall your old install. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation But reuse & reformat your existing partitions.